How a Proof of Zorn's Lemma Fails Without Choice
The following proof of Zorn's Lemma fails when the Axiom of Choice (or any of its equivalents) aren't assumed, but I am having trouble seeing how it fails. I am thinking this is related to the behaviour of amorphous sets but I can't get my head around it (and I could be wrong for other reasons anyway). The proof is by induction/contradiction and goes as follows:
Suppose $(P,\preceq)$ is a nonempty partially ordered set such that every chain $C \subseteq P$ is bounded above by an element in $P$. For the sake of contradiction, we further suppose that $P$ has no maximal elements.
Now, let $0 \neq \gamma \in \text{Ord}$ and suppose for all ordinals $\alpha < \gamma$ there exists $\{C_\alpha\}_{\alpha < \gamma}$ a sequence of well ordered chains in $P$ with the following properties:
$(1)$ For $\alpha < \gamma$, $C_\alpha = \{x_i\}_{i\leq \alpha}$,
$(2)$ For $\alpha, \beta < \gamma$, $\alpha < \beta$ implies $C_\alpha \subseteq C_\beta$, and
$(3)$ For $x_i, x_j \in C_\alpha$,  $i < j$ implies $x_i \prec x_j$.
Consider the set $\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma} C_\alpha$. It follows by the above assumptions that this is a chain in $P$, and is therefore bounded above by some element of $P$. That is, the set $U$ of upper bounds of $\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma} C_\alpha$ is nonempty. Because $P$ has no maximal elements, we have for each $u \in U$, the set $V_u = \{p \in P : u \prec p \}$ is also nonempty. Take $V = \bigcup_{u \in U} V_u$, which is then nonempty.
Define $C_\gamma := \left(\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma} C_\alpha \right) \cup \{x_\gamma\}$, where $x_\gamma$ is any element of $V$. For the sequence $\{C_\alpha\}_{\alpha \leq \gamma}$, properties $(1), (2),$ and $(3)$ above then hold for $\alpha, \beta \leq \gamma$. Since $P$ is nonempty, such a sequence of well ordered chains exists for $\gamma = 1$, so by induction, such a sequence of chains exists for all ordinals. Letting $H$ be the Hartog's number for $P$, the chain $C_H$ is a subset of $P$ and is in bijection with $H$. This produces an injection $H \to C_H \hookrightarrow P$, achieving contradiction. We conclude $P$ has at least one maximal element.

The only place in the above I could see my error being made is where I select an element $x_\gamma$ of $V$. This is the sort of thing it looks like you would need a choice function to do, but I don't see how it is different from declaring that $C_0 = \{x_0\} \subseteq P$ is a valid set, since both are nonempty. If this is where the problem was made, I can only think it is because $V$ was defined during the induction whereas $P$ was defined before the induction. If this is the case, I would appreciate some explanation for why declaring the existence of elements in a nonempty set in this way is problematic, and (if possible) how this goes wrong in the case of amorphous sets (if I'm not off base with considering them here to begin with). Further, if I assume the well ordering theorem to well order $P$ and take $x_\gamma = \min\{v \in V\}$ under this well order, is the proof now valid or are there other errors?
Other than that, maybe my use of induction was flawed in some other way. It looks right to me$-$ assume that holding for all $\alpha < \gamma$ implies it holds for $\gamma-$ but I'm not used to transfinite inductions, so please let me know if this (or something even simpler) was done incorrectly.

Just off the top of my head, how do you show the existence of $C_\alpha$ without choice?

Try writing down the actual induction hypothesis for your transfinite induction. It would be $\varphi(\alpha)$ being ${C_\lambda}_{\lambda < \alpha}$ exists, right? Now think what happens at any limit ordinal.

@JohannesKloos For the sake of induction I was assuming the family of chains $C_\alpha$ was known to exist, and that this was justified by demonstrating $C_0$ exists since $P$ is nonempty by assumption. That $C_\alpha$ exists for any ordinal would follow from induction, with $C_0$ as the base case. If choice is needed to show the existence of $C_\alpha$ for any $\alpha$ (specifically in picking an element from $V$), then I suppose you can't, but I'm confused on why I can't pick a single element from $V$ if I know it is nonempty.

If you were to prove all $\gamma$ have property $P(\gamma)$, the induction hypothesis at step $\gamma$ should be "all $\gamma'<\gamma$ have property $P(\gamma')$". If $P(\gamma')$ is "there is a desired sequence $(C_\alpha){\alpha<\gamma'}$" then your induction hypothesis is not much useful since $(C\alpha){\alpha<\gamma'}$ for different $\gamma'$ need not be compatible: for $\alpha<\gamma'<\gamma''<\gamma$, $C\alpha$ in $P(\gamma')$ and $C_\alpha$ in $P(\gamma'')$ need not be the same.

This is fine if $\gamma$ is a successor ordinal, since we would only need the $P(\gamma')$ right before $P(\gamma)$. It is not the case for a limit ordinal. To turn your idea into a proof you need "recursion", which is similar to, differnt from, and proved using induction.

In your proof, choice is used in the assertion "so by induction, such a sequence of chains exists for all ordinals". Let $\gamma$ be an arbitrary ordinal. Your argument before the assertion says that for all $\gamma'\le\gamma$ you can construct a new sequence $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha\le\gamma'}$ from an old sequence $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha<\gamma'}$ by choosing $x_{\gamma'}\in V$. Note that at each step $\gamma'$, even if $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha<\gamma'}$ is fixed, if you choose $C_{\gamma'}$ differently you have a different $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha\le\gamma'}$. So the construction of the whole sequence $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha\le\gamma}$ involves an infinite number of choices since there are infinitely many steps, for which the axiom of choice is necessary.
The detail of the induction goes as follows. For every sequence $(\gamma',C)=(C_\alpha)_{\alpha<\gamma'}$ define $V_{(\gamma',C)}$ to be the set of elements of $P$ greater than an upper bound of the union of the $C_\alpha$. It follows from your argument that $V_{(\gamma',C)}$ is not empty. From the axiom of choice, we know that we can choose $x_{(\gamma',C)}$ in each of $V_{(\gamma',C)}$. Now we can inductively define
$$C_{\gamma'}=\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma'}C_\alpha\cup\{x_{(\gamma',C)}\}$$
for all $\gamma'\le\gamma$, where $(\gamma',C)$ is the sequence corresponding to $\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma'}C_\alpha$. Without choice we can only have a finite number of choices to yield a function like $x_{(\gamma',C)}$ (unless you have an explicit formula to do so; e.g., assuming the well-ordering theorem which is equivalent to choice $x_{(\gamma',C)}=\min V_{(\gamma',C)}$ that you have mentioned is such a formula), but the number of sequences $(\gamma',C)$ is infinite.
